# Как перемещать QHboxLayout по виджету?

Tags: qt

Собственно как перемещать кнопку по виджету которая находиться на QHboxLayout программно без Qt Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью функции [setGeometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html#setGeometry).

Comment: собственно в этом и проблема, что если обращаться
`horizontal_layout->setGeometry(QRect(5,5,5,5));` то ничего не произойдет, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Надо ui->pushButton->setGeometry(QRect(5,5,5,5));

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось очень простым. Необходимо применить к слою на котором находиться виджет setContentMargins(left,top,right,down).  Соответственно данную функцию можно применить в переопределенной функции MouseMoveEvent для перемещения любого виджета внутри слоев.